# Relationship error when trying to embed and image into a Word document

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordml, wordprocessingml

I add a PNG image to a word 2010 document like this:

```
var imagePart = report.MainDocumentPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Png);
var imagePath = Path.Combine(imageFolder, "1.png");
var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open);
imagePart.FeedData(stream);
stream.Close();
```

I find the blip element of an empty Picture content control and change its reference property to point to the new image:

```
var blip = image.Descendants<Blip>().Single();
blip.Embed = report.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
```

I save the generated document, and validate it using the Open XML Productivity Tool. I get this error:

```
The relationship 'Ra4d8ccdc5256bb1' referenced by attribute 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships:embed' does not exist.
```

What are relationships? Why doesn't `AddImagePart` create one? How do I fix this error? When I open the generated document in Word the image doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. I don't know why, but I had to enclose

```
WordprocessingDocument report = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true)
```

with a `using` statement like this:

```
using(WordprocessingDocument report = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, true)) {
    //embed the image
}
```

withot `using` the document wasn't saved properly: relationships weren't created.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't fix the issue for me. Did anyone else find any other fixes?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430.aspx

Comment: The article explains how to add a completely new image, not how to reference it in an exiting picture content control

Comment: For Picture content control you can read Replacing a Picture in a Picture Content Control in an Open XML WordprocessingML Document @ http://ericwhite.com/blog/2011/03/27/replacing-a-picture-in-a-picture-content-control-in-an-open-xml-wordprocessingml-document/